# Fortify Unreleased Resource: Streams try with resource in loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, foreach, fortify, try-with-resources

Fortify find "Unreleased Resource: Streams" error for my script that I've already use try with resource :

```
public static void zipFiles(List<FileZipObject> fileList, File outFile) throws IOException {
    try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
         ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fileOutputStream)) {
        for (FileZipObject fileZipObject : fileList) {
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileZipObject.getFilePath())) { //  <------ This line
                ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(genEntryName(fileZipObject.getFileName()));
                zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                    zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void zipFiles(List<FileZipObject> fileList, File outFile) throws IOException {
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
ZipOutputStream zipOut = null;
try {
    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
    for (FileZipObject fileZipObject : fileList) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(fileZipObject.getFilePath());
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(genEntryName(fileZipObject.getFileName()));
            zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (zipOut != null) {
        zipOut.close();
    }
    if (fileOutputStream != null) {
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.

Comment: I fixed the problem with filnaly because even if it hits an exception, the finalizer will run and then release the resource